# Accessing a variable from a function and use it in an inner class

Tags: android, kotlin, location, global-variables

I have this getLastLocation function which gets the current user location and store them into location.latitude and location.longitude

```
fun getLastLocation(){
...
Log.d("Debug:" ,"Latitude: "+ location.latitude+" Longitude: "+location.longitude)
...
    }
```

And I have this inner class which gets the weather from openweathermap via the lat and lon values:

```
inner class WeatherTask : AsyncTask<String, Void, String>() {

        override fun doInBackground(vararg params: String?): String? {

            var latitude = location.latitude
            var longitude = location.longitude

            var response: String?
            try {
                response =
                    URL("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=$latitude&lon=$longitude&units=metric&appid=$api").readText(
                        Charsets.UTF_8
                    )
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                response = null
            }
            return response
        }
```

But it says my "location" is an unresolved reference, what is it? How do I fix that?

Comment: Is `location` a property of your outer class?

Comment: @Nicolas 
It is declared in the getLastLocation() function, but I skipped it
Here is the full code: https://shorturl.at/glADJ

Comment: Ah you can't use a local variable outside of the scope of its function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the location as parameter in the constructor:

```
inner class WeatherTask(var location: Location) : AsyncTask<String, Void, String>() {
```

call it as:

```
WeatherTask(location).execute()
```

Comment: The top code works perfect!!
But where should i put the "WeatherTask(location).execute()"?
Currently I put it in onCreate
But it shows "unresolved reference: location" and asks me to create an abstract property, what do I do here?

Comment: @SeriaAti you should call the AsynTask after getting the location

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't really understand what you mean
I call the getLastLocation() function in a setClickListener, do I put the execution code after it?
I've updated my full code, can you take a look at it?
Really huge thank

Comment: @SeriaAti What I meant to say is that you should call the AsyncTask in the callback `locationCallback` after you have successfully retrieved the location data ie. after `var lastLocation: Location = locationResult.lastLocation`

Comment: Problem solved, thank you very much!
I've been stuck on this for 2 weeks or more, thank you! :)
Hope you have a good night! (for me its 10pm)